# Vagrant AWS ELB's registering

Tags: amazon-web-services, vagrant

Hello I am trying to create instances in AWS using Vagrant. Everything works fine. But, if I add all the Availability zones to the ELB which has no instances and then if I create the instance in AWS using vagrant. Vagrant creates instance and at the time of registering it to the ELB it register's and then de-registers and terminates the instance? how do I resolve it? Can I register the instance to two ELB's using vagrant?

Editor's note:

SO's role is, the link is not trusted. So I pasted Vagrantfile here directly.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu_aws"
  config.vm.box_url = "https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/raw/master/dummy.box"
  config.vm.synced_folder "../.", "/vagrant", id: "vagrant-root"
  config.vm.provider :aws do |aws, override|
    aws.keypair_name = "development"
    override.ssh.private_key_path = "~/.ssh/development.pem"
    aws.instance_type = "t1.micro"
    aws.security_groups = "development"
    aws.ami = "ami-c5afc2ac"
    aws.elb = [elb1, elb2]
    override.ssh.username = "ubuntu"
    aws.tags = {
      'Name' => 'Web App',
     }
  end
```

Comment: it is hard for us to guess your environment. if can, provide the sample of `Vagrantfile` you used.

Comment: http://pastie.org/10184148

Here, is the sample how am trying to add two elbs to the created instance but it fails.

Comment: can you try with one elb first: `aws.elb = 'elb1'`, then try with two but quote it `aws.elb = ['elb1', 'elb2']`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works well with one elb but it fails when I use an array of elb's I have tried with the quotes but no success..

Comment: can you try : `aws.elb = 'elb1'  aws.elb = 'elb2'`

Comment: No success with that config also :(

Comment: Actually what's happening with this is the elb which am naming second the instance is getting registered to that and skipping the first.